# Angular2 - pass variable with EventEmitter by timeout function to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have issue with Event Emitter in child component.

I want to pass variable with EventEmitter to parent component, but with usage timeout function. Now it's look like this:

CHILD:

```
export class AlertSuccess implements OnChanges {

    @Input() success: SuccessCRM;
    @Output() emitCollapse:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    private info_ico: string = require('../../public/images/iconInfoTip.png');
    public state: boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    collapseAlert () {
        let alert = document.getElementById('success');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("BEFORE EMITTED STATE!!!!!: ", this.state );
            console.log(this.emitCollapse);
            this.emitCollapse.emit(this.state); 
        }, 500);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges):void {
        console.log("CHANGES: ", this.success);
        this.collapseAlert();
    }
}
```

In parent everything is normal, I have method which I passed via template.

Emitter is working without timeout function. Please help me implement it into timeout!

Regards 
Bosper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Arrow function` to point correct `this`.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("BEFORE EMITTED STATE!!!!!: ", this.state );
    console.log(this.emitCollapse);
    this.emitCollapse.emit(this.state); 
}, 500);
```

Comment: Just as an improvement and as a comment for @Uland remember to clean up your timeout inside of your ngOnDestroy.

Comment: @camaron I don't think so clearing timeout would matter, it `collapseAlert` function gets called, `setTimeout` will get called once only & then its never been called. If it would `setInterval` then OP have to clear it in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle event..